# Alpaca ReadOnly after manual modification

Tags: forms, readonly, alpacajs

I'm using Alpaca forms to display some information :

```
$("#object_details").alpaca({
    "schema": map[obj_type],
    "data": JSON.stringify(json_data["content"]),
    "options": {
        "label": "some label"
    }
})
```

So I have some JSON Schema defined :

```
json_schema = {
        "title": "Host",
        "en_description": "Host object",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "addr": {
                "en_description": "IP addresses",
                "title":"Host addresses",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "ipv4": {
                        "en_description": "Host IPv4 address",
                        "title":"IPv4 address",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "ipv4",
                        "readonly":True
                    },
                    "ipv6" : {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
           }
}
```

As you can see I got some field on ReadOnly, and some others on edit mode.
I want to make a modified-field to become readonly. For example, here, if I modify the ipv6 field, once I send my forms, the ipv6 field will become readonly.

Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by setting the read-only option to true after you submit the form like the following:

```
field.options.readonly = true;
field.refresh();
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/x3m0xLvg) for this.I hope this is what you're looking for, tell me if you need something else. I'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't work. Well, it works, but it's not what I expected to do ! :(
Actually this will make the field ReadOnly but not save it as readOnly, I mean, if I refresh the page, the field won't be readOnly no more ! 
What I need is the field to stay readOnly, forever, BUT only for this data set, if I load another data set with the same JSON Schema, the field won't be readOnly !
I hope my explications are clear enough !

Comment: For this you should save the data to DB after submitting your form, then before you initialize your alpaca form you should retrieve those data and set the to the form, after you do that use the postRender function to change the readonly value to true if your field has data in DB!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but a huge thanks to you ! 

I've finally made it, using exactly your method. I've added a field in my json containing the differents fields to put on "read-only". On each field of my form, I've got an "Observable" which is triggered when data are modified, and put the field's path in my json. Then I save it into my DB.

When I have to display the form, I use the postRender callback to go through my json field containing my read-only fields, and put appropriates fields on readOnly !

Thank you !